# Neo4j - Faster to rely on relationships or to duplicate/store data of objects I'm referencing?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and still experimenting / changing up my whole understanding of building databases with it.

My question is, given an object of type X that needs data from another object of type X (e.g. object 2 has a comment that we want to get when querying for object 1), is it faster to just store a duplicate of that comment in object 1, or does Neo4j work faster with relationships (maybe "faster" isn't the right term.  Can it scale?).  Which would be better if I want it to be possible for the "chain" of relationships (object 1 needing the comment of object 2 and the comment of the object that object 2 is pointing to... so object 3).

Sorry if that's confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it faster to just store a duplicate of that comment in object 1?

**Don't do that.**

May you imagine the effect on maintainability to duplicate such data ?
The essence and the whole benefit of Neo4j is to **traverse nodes through relationships.**

You thought like if Neo4j was just a document-oriented database.
It's a **graph** database.

In 95% of cases, you should model your neo4j data as they are linked in real life, since the benefit of the graph is to "model" the real life.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was hoping to hear.  My brain is still shackled to the olden ways.